# Buying stock at discount yields unintuitive rate of return

Tags: finance

My employer offers an Employee Stock Purchase Program (ESPP).  Long story short, worst case scenario is that they will purchase stock on my behalf at a 15% discount and then I will immediately sell it.  I am confused as to why my gain is 17.65% as opposed to 15%.  Where does the number 17.65% come from?  It is not intuitive to me.  Example calculation:

On purchase day stock price is 10 USD.
I get to buy it using my discount so, I buy it at (.85*10) = 8.50 USD
I then immediately sell it for 10 USD.

So my gain is (10-8.50)/8.50 = 17.65%

Comment: Because your gain of 1.5 is not compared to the "theorical" cost of 10 but to the effective cost : 8.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $15\%$ discount is multiplied by the market price to give your purchase price.  The gain is calculated as a percentage of the discount price, which is lower.  As the absolute discount is the same, the gain on sale must be a higher percentage.

The effect is general and gets larger as the discount percentage increases.  If you get a $50\%$ discount you would buy the stock at $5$.  The immediate profit would then be $100\%$ because you can sell it at $10$.  If your discount is $x$, you buy the stock for $1-x$ and sell it for $1$, so the profit is $\frac x{1-x} \gt x$ because the denominator is less than $1$.